# Prove by definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n!} = 0$

I have no idea how to proceed with this. Usually I start with a preliminary computation and solve for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$ from the definition of the limit:

$|\dfrac{1}{n!} - 0| < \epsilon$

Here, I do not see an approach to solve for n.

Comment: Solving for $n$ is **totally** unnecessary. You are not asked to find the smallest $N$ such that beyond it $|a_n|\lt \epsilon$. You are only asked to show there **is** an $N$ such that beyond it, $\dots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $$\frac1{n!}\le\frac1n$$ for $n>0$. Now use the Archimedean property of the reals.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try to find a $n$ for which 
$$
n!\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}
$$
or as Brian suggested, you only need to find $n$ such that
$$
n\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}.
$$
In either case, it proves that the limit goes to $0$.